# Does Thread.CurrentThread always return same instance?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Can I make `Dictionary<Thread, object>` to store thread's data and use Thread.CurrentThread to retreive it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can, but you'd also need to synchronize (as `Dictionary<,>` isn't thread-safe).

Alternatives:

- [`ThreadStaticAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx)
- [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) (.NET 4)

Of course, one benefit of using a dictionary over `ThreadStaticAttibute` is that you don't need to worry about garbage as much, or indeed black magic. If you're using .NET 4 though, `ThreadLocal<T>` is possibly your best option.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you could, if you want to access other threads' data, but you should take a look at ThreadStaticAttribute or ThreadLocal first, it's much better if threads only need to see their own data.